# Create a form as a service in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

What I'd like to be able to do from any controller is:

```
$register = $this->get('register_manager');
return $this->render(
    'AcmeUserBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
     array(
         'form' => $register->getRegistrationForm(),
         )
 );
```

And in my template

```
<form>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
</form>
```

**Here's how I have set up so far**

In my `Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` I have

```
parameters:
    register_manager.class: Acme\UserBundle\Manager\RegisterManager

services:
    register_manager:
        class:     %register_manager.class%
        arguments: [@form.factory]
```

In `RegisterManager.php` I have

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Manager;

use Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;

class RegisterManager
{

    protected $formFactory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }


    public function getRegistrationForm()
    {
        return $this->formFactory->createBuilder(new RegistrationType());
    }
}
```

And in `Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType` I have:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username','text');
        $builder->add('email','email');
        $builder->add('password','password');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }
}
```

I know the `RegistrationType()` works as I've had it in a controller. My problem is with setting up `RegisterManager` as a service, I can't get the right components in there and I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're encountering? What do you mean by "can't get the right components in there"? Right now it should work as expected.

Comment: right now, in my RegistrationManager service I need to be able to call ```createForm(new RegistrationType())``` and return that for the controller to be able to pass it to the template but I'm not sure where ```createForm()``` is defined and how to make it available in this service class. In Symfony Forms documentation it's accessed like ```$this->createForm()``` but how would I do that in my service class? I don't think it's part of ```FormFactoryInterface``` http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: The FOSUserBundle uses the form.factory service directly without the need of a RegisterManager class, check it out, https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/profile.xml

Comment: Check out this article that explains exactly how to register your form as a service.  http://www.webtipblog.com/define-a-symfony-2-form-as-a-service/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're almost there, it seems. To get a Form object from your service, you should use [`FormFactoryInterface::create()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactoryInterface.php#L14) instead of `FormFactoryInterface::createBuilder()`

The reason why `$this->createForm()` works in controllers is because every controller is extending the [base controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php), which happens to implement this method.

I have found my IDE's ability to link to specific Symfony files highly helpful and I suggest you use one, if you already aren't. There's also a git repository, which you can find [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony).