# Symfony 2 forms - access parameters.ini from the form class

Tags: forms, parameters, symfony

I need to access `parameters.ini` from a form.

Of-course I can access from the controller:

```
$myVal = $this->container->getParameter('my_val');
```

Pass it to the controller:

```
$demoForm = $this->createForm(new demoFormType($myVal), $demoObject);
```

and in the form to save this value which is passed to the constructor (which, of-course, should be explicitly implemented).

However, this form is used in several controllers, so it would be much cleaner to simply access in some "magic" way from the form class.

Is it possible??? I couldn't find any answer for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure doing it the way you suggest is the best idea.  Forms shouldn't be config-bound like that.

Instead, maybe you could create a new controller to inherit from.

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Your\Bundle\Form\Type\demoFormType;

class FormAwareController extends Controller
{
  protected function createDemoForm( $demoObject )
  {
    $myVal = $this->container->getParameter( 'my_val' );
    return $this->createForm( new demoFormType( $myVal, $demoObject ) );
  }
}
```

And then, extend this class where you need to

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Controller;

class SampleController extends FormAwareController
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $demoObject = new stdClass; // or whatever
    $form = $this->createDemoForm( $demoObject );

    // etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: Form Aware controllers in S2?  Might want to rethink that a bit.

Comment: I've thought about it. Now what? It's clear the form-as-a-service option is better but I don't know what kind feedback you expect to elicit from me with curt comments like that.

Comment: Forms are distinct from Controllers, so forms should not inherit from Controllers ...

Comment: @Jay Ok, so, this is an old question and an old answer, But even given that *and* my (now) greater familiarity with the Symfony platform, **for the record**, this answer *does not* suggest creating a form that inherits from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

[Define your form as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107179/create-a-form-as-a-service-in-symfony2) then pass parameters to it using the %parameter% notation.  Your controllers can then just grab the service without needing to know anything about the initialization process.

The technique is also very useful for setting entity managers and other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Process to send parameters.ini value to view in Symfony2

parameters.ini

```
app_name = "Application Name";
```

in Controller

```
$data = array(
app_name =>$this->container->getParameter( 'app_name' );
)
return $this->render('Bundle:Home:index.html.twig', $data);
```

in View

```
{{app_name}}
```