# Access session from formType in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to get session data into my forms but i don't know how to do.

I could pass it to the constructor of my FormType but the FormType that actually use the session is **nested 3 levels deeper** in the main form.
So i think that it is dirty to pass the session object in each constructor of each form type like this :

```
->add('name', new NestedFormType($this->session))
```

I also thought about using formsType as service. So i would have a parent for each of my formsType that should be injected with session.

But how can i do that without defininf all my **forms as services** ?

Futhermore, i can't access to the `DIC` inside of my FormTypes. So, it's ok for the creation of the first formType object (which is created in the controller which can access to `DIC`) but the nested FormTypes cannot be instianciated from their parent.

Is there a clean solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define this parent form as a service and pass the session as the argument.

look at this question: [Create a form as a service in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107179/create-a-form-as-a-service-in-symfony2)

Comment: I thought about that but how should i create child objects if their parent is a service but they are not ?

Comment: I think you can pass all data what you want to form constructor in a options parameter :)

Comment: Maybe, but i have to pass it from form to form until i reached the form in which i need the session

Comment: So forget about a parent one. Just create the embeded form as a service and do it in that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define services for your higher level form types as long as you refer to the inner, injected form type by its alias:

NestedFormType service definition:

```
nested.form.type:
    class: Type\NestedFormType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: nested_form }
    arguments: [ @security.context ]
```

NestedFormType:

```
class NestedFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $security_context;

    public function __construct($security_context)
    {
        $this->security_context = $security_context;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // do something with $this->security_context
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'nested_form';
    }
}
```

ParentFormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name', 'nested_form'); 
    // 'nested_form' matches service definition and NestedFormType::getName()
}
```