# How to make Symfony2 entity formtype show entities of type A but save them as type B?

Tags: forms, symfony

I currently have the option in my application for a user to select favorite Items from a list. The form element is of type Entity and shows the list of objects. Users can select a number of them as their personal favorite.

However, although the list must show Items, what has to be stored is actually a FavoritedItem (which contains extra information about when/how the user favorited his Item).

I cannot figure out how to convert the entity types so that the user can pick from a list of Item entities but that the form stores FavoritedItems connected to the user.

Comment: How are your entities set up? What is the relation between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your entity has a relationship with FavoritedItem, when you are creating your form, don't include that field, but a dummy field to contain the data the user selected:

```
$builder->add('favs', null, array('property_path' => false, 'type'='entity'.....));
```

Find this line:

```
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
    }
```

and for each of your items, set the appropriate FavoritedItem on your entity. It would look something like:

```
$favorites = $form->get('favs')->getData();

foreach($favorites as $f){
    $FavItem = new FavoritedItem($f);
    $yourEntity->addFavorite($FavItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to handle all of this inside the Form? I'd rather not move the logic to the controller due to reusability.

Comment: If you want to use the same field type in many forms, create your own field type (http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). If you want to use the same field type you are using now, create a custom transformer (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) You may want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107179/create-a-form-as-a-service-in-symfony2